# jQuery get amount of values set to true in multidimensional object

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble with a little script I am making, and I can't figure out how to do it. I've got an object which looks like this:

```
var data =
        {
            1: {
                1: {
                    team: 0,
                    set: false
                },
                2: {
                    team: 0,
                    set: false
                },
                3: {
                    team: 0,
                    set: false
                }
            },
            2: {
                1: {
                    team: 0,
                    set: false
                },
                2: {
                    team: 0,
                    set: false
                },
                3: {
                    team: 0,
                    set: false
                }
            },
            3: {
                1: {
                    team: 0,
                    set: false
                },
                2: {
                    team: 0,
                    set: false
                },
                3: {
                    team: 0,
                    set: false
                }
            }
        };
```

Now, the first 1,2 and 3 are the row, then the other 1,2,3 in each one are the cells. Now I need to find out for example, how many of the set elements are set to true in a given row. So for example:

```
var data =
        {
            1: {
                1: {
                    team: 0,
                    set: false
                },
                2: {
                    team: 0,
                    set: true
                },
                3: {
                    team: 0,
                    set: true
                }
            }
        };
```

If I wanted it for row 1, the above should return 2, because there is 2 options set to true.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate over your row and count the cell element where `set` is `true`:

```
function countTrueSetInRow (data, rowNum) {
    var count = 0 ;
    jQuery.each(data[rowNum], function (i, d) {
        if (d.set) { count ++ ; }
    });
    return count ;
}

function countTrueSetInCol (data, colNum) {
    var count = 0 ;
    jQuery.each(data, function (i, d) {
        if (d[colNum].set) { count ++ ; }
    });
    return count ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if this is possible for vertical aswell? So, I need to for example get the amount of data[1][1]["set"], data[2][1]["set"] and data[3][1]["set"].

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over every element. In Javascript you can access an object property as an array element.

```
function countTrue(data,element){
    var count=0;
    for (var i in data[element]){
        if (data[element][i]["set"])
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

In your example, `countTrue(data,1)` will return 2.